# No supported devices found with name or id matching '00008030-00094D38363B802E'

Tags: android, ios, flutter

The flutter App is running successfully in all emulators on android, ios, and on android devices. Unfortunately not running anymore on my iPhone device. kindly help me with an **Updated solution** for this issue. I tried many suggestions and solutions on StackOverflow and GitHub but still the same issue. I **invalidate caches**, I switch to **master Chanelle** , done `flutter clean, flutter channel master, flutter upgrade,`,
tried `flutter run -d <device ID>` and quite a lot.

Comment: Have you added your iOS device-id in your provision profile?

Comment: Yes it's added.... I renewed my membership 3 months ago and kept the same device. I check again and the same ID is there, type: iphone but status: (nothing is written)